Kong AI Proxy Plugin: Correct Parameters for Configuring a Self-Hosted LLM on Kong AI Gateway
(This question relates to using Kong API Gateway as a way to offer multiple LLM APIs as a service)
I have a number of self-hosted LLMs which I want to access via Kong's AI Gateway (i.e "A.I Proxy Plugin").
Each self-hosted LLM is running on kubernetes shared with the Kong API gateway which has the Kong AI Plugin configured.
I have validated the Kong AI plugin is working by configuring OpenAI (SaaS) as it's upstream a.i service. I can access OpenA.I via the Kong API gateway.
However, I am unable to correctly configure my self-hosted LLMs to be accessed vi the proxy. I believe this is due to the lack of detailed, clear documentation around the many specific cases for configuring self-hosted LLMs on Kong AI gateway.
Here is the procedure I use to configure an LLM on Kong AI gateway:

Configure a Service
Configure a Route
Configure the AI Plugin
Test with curl.

Worked example:

Configure a Service

curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/services \
  --data "name=ai-proxy" \
  --data "url=http://localhost:32000"

{"retries":5,"write_timeout":60000,"tags":null,"ca_certificates":null,"port":32000,"id":"0ea9a00b-8417-487e-b4d0-c03826e03d5f","client_certificate":null,"created_at":1730257354,"updated_at":1730257354,"tls_verify":null,"tls_verify_depth":null,"host":"localhost","connect_timeout":60000,"protocol":"http","read_timeout":60000,"path":null,"enabled":true,"name":"ai-proxy"}



Configure a Route

curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/services/ai-proxy/routes \
  --data "name=llama2-chat" \
  --data "paths[]=~/llama2-chat$"

 
{"path_handling":"v0","destinations":null,"service":{"id":"0ea9a00b-8417-487e-b4d0-c03826e03d5f"},"methods":null,"id":"81f7d8c8-82b8-487e-b1c7-df566f31ead8","strip_path":true,"created_at":1730257395,"updated_at":1730257395,"name":"llama2-chat","preserve_host":false,"headers":null,"regex_priority":0,"paths":["~/llama2-chat$"],"tags":null,"hosts":null,"request_buffering":true,"response_buffering":true,"https_redirect_status_code":426,"protocols":["http","https"],"sources":null,"snis":null}


Configure the AI Plugin

traiano@lolserver:~/scripts$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/routes/llama2-chat/plugins   \
        --data "name=ai-proxy"   \
        --data "config.route_type=llm/v1/completions" \
        --data "config.model.provider=llama2"   \
        --data "config.model.name=llama2"   \
        --data "config.model.options.llama2_format=openai"   \
         --data "config.model.options.upstream_url=http://lolcorp-llmserver.vllm/llm/v1/completions"

{"config":{"route_type":"llm/v1/completions","max_request_body_size":8192,"model":{"options":{"output_cost":null,"temperature":null,"anthropic_version":null,"top_p":null,"azure_instance":null,"bedrock":null,"azure_api_version":"2023-05-15","azure_deployment_id":null,"llama2_format":"openai","upstream_path":null,"mistral_format":null,"upstream_url":"http://lolcorp-llmserver.vllm/llm/v1/completions","gemini":null,"max_tokens":256,"top_k":null,"input_cost":null},"provider":"llama2","name":"llama2"},"auth":null,"model_name_header":true,"logging":{"log_payloads":false,"log_statistics":false},"response_streaming":"allow"},"tags":null,"protocols":["grpc","grpcs","http","https"],"service":null,"route":{"id":"81f7d8c8-82b8-487e-b1c7-df566f31ead8"},"id":"89e9c9fb-9599-4067-9285-d27e94703f3b","enabled":true,"consumer":null,"instance_name":null,"updated_at":1730257456,"created_at":1730257456,"name":"ai-proxy"}



Test with curl.

traiano@lolserver:~/scripts$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/llama2-chat \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{ "messages": [ { "role": "system", "content": "You are a mathematician" }, { "role": "user", "content": "What is 1+1?"} ] }'

{"error":{"message":"[llm/v1/chat] message format is not compatible with [llm/v1/completions] route type"}}


What could be the configuration problem?
I have seen this documentation, however, it doesn't seem to cover my specific LLMs: https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/ai-proxy/

Do you maybe want to use the "llm/v1/chat" and not the "llm/v1/completions" route type?
I see that the message you are sending to the endpoint looks like it is intended for the "llm/v1/chat". Try to create a plugin of that type and see if that helps.

Thanks, that helps. It's one of the many misconfigurations in my setup.
